# How to Setup gradle-2.2.1-all.zip Manually

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle

I want to run my unit test with this command

```
gradlew.bat connectedInstrumentTest
```

But it tries to download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

And my corporal network blocks it. Hence, I want to setup the zip manually, I already downloaded it from browser.

The ways I failed are listed below

- Pasting it in Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\
  gradle-2.2.1 didn't work
- File -> Settings -> Build execution, Deployment -> Build Tools and
  defining the gradle home directory didn't work

Any suggestions except these will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The network blocked the script from downloading the zip file, but you were able to do so successfully?

Comment: have you checked `Offline work` in Global Gradle setting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your command you're using the [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html). The Gradle wrapper is a thin wrapper around the real Gradle bin. It's intended to be checked in to your source control and it then downloads the version of Gradle you've defined in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. The advantage here is the version of Gradle used in the build is directly tied to the source control.

You have 2 options:

- use the `gradle` command instead of `gradlew` - this will use the `gradle` that's installed on the local machine (assumes that 'gradle' is on the PATH). The drawback here is you have to have installed Gradle somewhere before the build will work.
- change `distributionUrl` in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to point to a different URL and host that file yourself somewhere. You get all the advantages of the wrapper but fix the problems you're having downloading it.

Comment: This works! If you have a Samba/FS host, you could change it to something like: distributionUrl=file:///user/me/downloads/gradle.zip

Answer (score 9):

Solution :

1). Delete the C:\Users\username\.gradle folder

2). Download http://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

3). Create a new project in android studio.

4). When this time it stucks at gradle building, Force close the android studio.

5) Now go to C:\Users\username\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\c64ydeuardnfqctvr1gm30w53 (the end directory name may be different)

6) Delete gradle-2.2.1-all.zip.lck and other files from this directory.

7) Paste the new downloaded gradle-2.2.1-all.zip here.

8) Run the android studio. :)

Comment: I havn't Dist folder after the path C:\Users\username\.gradle\wrapper\

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, this error occurs due to brake in internet or slow connection network.
A gradle file downloads partially, this zip file isn't extractable and neither does re-download using Android Studio work.

So, to solve this problem, you have to:

1. Delete the gradle download folder or download the gradle zip file manually and configure using the following method
2. Download requires gradle and past the zip into `C:\Users\your_pc_name\.gradle\wrapper\dists`
3. Finally, open Android Studio and run the project.

*The gradle version care fully before downloading*

[image: Gradle name]