# Gradle error : Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, mobile, html-framework-7

I have this error in the apps that I'm currently building on:

```
C:\mobile\xtern_mobile\ST>cordova run android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\myPC\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\mobile\xtern_mobile\ST\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\mobile\xtern_mobile\ST\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
    at C:\Users\myPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova:30:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I've tried already the suggestions in
[How to Setup gradle-2.2.1-all.zip Manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405947/how-to-setup-gradle-2-2-1-all-zip-manually), but the same error keeps appearing.

Is there any other way or thing I need to do?

Comment: I don't really do android but here's my suggestions: Thats quite an old version of gradle, are you sure you don't want to use a more recent version? Additionally `http://services.gradle.org/distributions/` seems to redirect to a https version of the site which could explain why you can't download with http. IIRC old versions of maven have a similar issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use https: replace

`http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip` with `https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip`

The problem is that you use `http` instead of `https`. You can check it in your browser and link with `https` will start downloading file while your link with `http` will return 403 error