# Libgdx iOS project on android studio

Tags: ios, android-studio, libgdx

I'm using android studio as a ide to run Libgdx iOS project, but it always start to download gradle 2.4-all.zip file while running 'command gradlew ios:launchIPhoneSimulator', and stuck after some time in downloading file. why android-studio always downlaod gradle 2.4-all.zip file while running libgdx iOS porject on android studio.

Comment: I hope that you can find solution here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580873/android-studio-stuck-at-gradle-download-on-create-new-project][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580873/android-studio-stuck-at-gradle-download-on-create-new-project

Comment: Thanks, it works for me, but it really take long time to download gradle file.