# android studio stuck on new project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I wanted to create a new porject in **Android Studio 2.0**, so I choosed a name and location for my new project, then I have clicked on the *Next* button.

after that, in `Target Android Devices` window, I've choosed a minumum SDK, then clicked on *Next* button again, but the `new project` proccess will stuck on a window which is saying **Installing Requeted Components** and below code is error that shows in Evenet Log : `NullPointerException: null`

```
null

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.repository.util.InstallerUtil.resolveCompleteArchiveUrl(InstallerUtil.java:194)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.install(BasicInstaller.java:76)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.legacy.SmwOldApiDirectInstall$InstallTask.run(SmwOldApiDirectInstall.java:203)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

How can i pass this error and create a new project now?

***Note: my SDK is full and I have every platform in it**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this by installing bundle version.

Answer (score 0):

It is not stuck, it will take some time normally 5-7 mins , it also depends upon internet connection, so wait for some time. It will take time only for first launch.

Update: Check the latest log file in

> C:\Users\.gradle\daemon\x.y

folder to see what it's downloading.[Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580873/android-studio-stuck-at-gradle-download-on-create-new-project?rq=1)

Comment: I'm using offline gradle

Comment: I don't think using offline mode u can create a new project.

Comment: I didn't change anything in my computer !

Comment: Where is the log file in Linux?