# When I try creating a new project in Android studio installed in my Mac it doesn't get created and it gets stuck.Can someone tell me whats happening?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I am a new Mac user and I installed Android studio in my Mac.Installation went smooth.I then tried creating a new project however the project does not get created and it gets stuck forever with the message 'Building 'My Application'Gradle project info'.
Another point to note , when I disconnect my network the project gets created however the gradle sync doesn't happen.
So I imagine in the first place ,when I am connected to the network and try creating a new project probably Studio is trying to download more files etc ?If so how do I see whats happening behind the scene and understand its ETA ?
Can someone help ?

Comment: Can you have a look at the Gradle Console and leave here any messages you can see there? That inputs would help on debugging.

Comment: My original issue was I couldn't even get to the console as it was stuck in the first step(Trying to create a new project).Fortunately the issue seem to be resolved for me,I waited patiently for almost 30 mins after clicking on create a new project and the project got created,it appears that I had to wait for some stuff to download in the background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580873/android-studio-stuck-at-gradle-download-on-create-new-project?rq=1 seems like your issue is quite similar here?

Comment: Yeah,Thanks for letting me know :-)